# Do I need to remove this DT Swiss ring nut? (360 hub)

Tags: replacement, rear-wheel, bearings, tools

I'm swapping bearings on Roval Traverse rear hub, which is [said to have](https://rovalcomponents.com/products/2019-traverse) DT Swiss 360 internals, 3-pawl.

Do I therefore need to remove the ring nut as per normal DT Swiss instructions? If so I'll need to source the tool.

There is such a small difference between the diameters of the ring and the bearing, are all DT Swiss hubs like this/is it normal??

[image: DT Swiss rear hub ring nut and drive side bearing]

Comment: According to the spec, the Outer Diameter of the bearing is 28 mm but no tolerance quoted.  Do you have anything to measure the Internal Diameter of those teeth with accuracy?  Or if you already have the replacement bearing, try fitting it into the pawl teeth to see if it has clearance ?

Comment: @Criggie The replacement bearing doesn't slip past the teeth nicely, though it will wedge in there, which does kind of indicate that the teeth need to come out. I suppose I'm after confirmation that this is normal for DT Swiss internals, and that however close the sizes _seem_ to be, the ring is in the way and this is normal.

Comment: From the website ''trouble-free performance, and easy maintenance are at the core of the Traverse.'' Lol

Comment: @JoeK lol yes indeed, that passage felt somewhat ironic to read. One wheel I did since, I managed to deform the _tool_ in trying to create the required torque on the wheel

Answer (score 9):

DT Swiss states that on pawl type rear hubs, the ring nut must be removed in order to remove the driver-side bearing. See section 2.7, page 9, in this manual from DT Swiss:
https://www.dtswiss.com/pmt/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/00/00/00/89/7/MAN_WXD10000000897S_WEB_EN_001.pdf

Edit:
Regarding the question "if all DT Swiss hubs is like this", well no. The newer ratchet type rear hubs (e.g. 350, 240, 180 and model year from 2015 onward) have slightly smaller bearings on the drive side and therefor the driver side bearing can be removed without first removing the ring nut on those. More information is available from the DT Swiss manual for ratchet type rear hubs, section 2.5, page 9. Link here:
https://www.dtswiss.com/pmt/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/00/00/00/89/6/MAN_WXD10000000896S_WEB_EN_001.pdf

Best regards
Magnus

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the normal arrangement on DT Swiss 3-pawl hub; to replace the drive side bearing, the ring nut needs to be removed using the tool (bought or borrowed). This rebranded '360' hub is no different to normal.

The bearing will not pass through the ring nut, even though it looks like it maybe could.

The ring nut will have tightened in use, so secure the tool in a stiff vice to stand up to the large torque required. A couple of toe straps work nicely to strap a long (e.g. 2m) length of wood etc. on the tyre to create leverage on the hub.